# Initialize std::priority_queue just with the container

Tags: c++, initialization, std

Having defined the following aliases,

```
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
using minheap = priority_queue<T, vector<T>, greater<T>>;
```

I was wondering if there is a way to initialize a `priority_queue` by just calling the constructor with a container (in this case, a vector):

```
minheap<int> queue (vec);  // vec is some vector of integers
```

But it doesn't seem to work that way. What does work is using the range-based initializer,

```
minheap<int> queue (vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

which is extremely ugly considering I want to use the whole vector.

The closest alternative I've found is `priority_queue(const Compare& comp, const Container& ctnr);`. I would have thought that the `greater<int>` wouldn't have been needed, since I already explicitly specified the `greater` comparison in the `minheap` alias declaration.

Is there a way to do something like `minheap<int> q (vec);`? Or do I have to stick to `(vec.begin(), vec.end())`?

Comment: @Anakhand It's more a tragedy of class design in my opinion. There's no constructor that accepts only a container. I feel like if the interface were designed post-Ranges, we might see that, but for now we have the iterator constructor that is so prevalent. The reason you have to pass an *instance* of `std::greater<int>` is that your Comparator might have state that you want it to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[No, there is no constructor that only takes a container instance.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue)

There is an overload that only takes the *comparator* instance and default-constructs the *container*, namely `explicit priority_queue(const Compare& compare) : priority_queue(compare, Container()) { }`, but not the other way around.

The closest one can get is `priority_queue( const Compare& compare, const Container& cont );`, which needs to be given a comparator instance explicitly.